# Is there a standard definition of resolution for arbitrary clauses?

Tags: proof-theory, boolean-formulas, resolution

Knuth defines in [1] a resolution operator for arbitrary clauses which sets $C = C' \diamond C'' = (C' \lor C'')$ when there is no literal $x$ such that $x \in C'$ and $\neg x \in C''$. I skimmed over [2], [3] and [4] and could not find any references to this particular style.

Why is this definition sensible for general clauses? How is it different from, say, defining $C = C' \diamond C'' = \top$, a tautology, in such case?

---

[1] Knuth, TAOCP, Volume 4 Fascicle 6, Satisfiability

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)

[3] *Buss, Samuel R. (ed.)*, Handbook of proof theory, Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics. 137. Amsterdam: Elsevier. 811 p. (1998). [ZBL0898.03001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0898.03001).

[4] *Krajíček, Jan*, [**Proof complexity**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/9781108242066),  [ZBL07044161](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:07044161).

Comment: I'd need to read up on the diamond operator but certainly removing multiple literals and their negations does not work - after all ¬A ∨ ¬B ≠ ¬(A ∨ B). Perhaps resolution is defined differently then?

Comment: And perhaps another rather obvious observation: the cut rule can be seen as resolution on general formulas (the unifying substitution has to be handled differently though).